# Create a progress bar in android that change its color while it is progressing and inverse progress bar

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar, drawable

I want to have a progress bar which goes as a countdown from 10 to 0 and I want from 10 to 7 to be green then from 7 to 3 yellow and from 3 to 0 red. Can that be accomplished only in XML?
I took a look at [Android change Horizonal Progress bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745814/android-change-horizonal-progress-bar-color) but that just changes the color of the bar, doesn't give me three color bar.
Second question is how can I make the progress bar goes from max to 0 instead 0 to max? I mean, I want it to start full and then getting empty.

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have different colors for the progress bar, you have to play around with background drawable for the progress bar (please take a look at this example http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~financisto-dev/financisto/trunk/view/head:/res/drawable/progress_horizontal_budget.xml)

To go from max to 0 just use `setProgress` and set it to max first, then decrement..

Comment: ohhhhhh my god.... wasted hours to get this.... champ u r amazing.... keep it up...