# change color of horizontal progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have a static progress bar which just displays a stagnant data in the bar. i want to change the default color i.e. yellow. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745814/android-change-horizonal-progress-bar-color) solution didnt help as my progress bar became a horizontal gray animation. 
Please help.

Comment: Try this too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android

Comment: your question is related to [this][1].



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android

Comment: @vinayak thanks. It worked. Can you tell how can I change the gray color in the progress bar as well? I mean the gray color that displays the remaining region.

Answer (score 0):

You can custom progress bar style.

Look like bellow:

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/whiteprogress"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:maxHeight="18dip"
    android:minHeight="18dip" />
```

And create whiteprogress.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="2dip" />

            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="#26A69A"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#26A69A"
                android:startColor="#26A69A" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="2dip" />

                <gradient
                    android:angle="270"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="2dip" />

                <gradient
                    android:angle="270"
                    android:endColor="#ffffff"
                    android:startColor="#ffffff" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```