# Horizontal Progress bar with two colors which changes alternatively based on the timer

Tags: android, timer, progress-bar

i am able to achieve the progress bar with two colors by the help of this link

[Android change Horizonal Progress bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745814/android-change-horizonal-progress-bar-color)

In my app i am using a timer and its for 1 min, i need the progress bar to change the color to red for first 5 sec and after then blue for next 5 sec and this should repeat until the timer is done i.e., for 1 min.

Answer (score 0):

I would have another timer set to 5 seconds on repeat.
When it ticks have it swap the colours.