# How to create Custom Horizontal progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar

Please help to create horizontal progress bar like this[image]

Comment: here is a PSD file http://goo.gl/ANcyhs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need a custom progress bar. Use `style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"` in your layout xml file. You will also need to use 
`ProgressBar.incrementProgressBy(int progress);`

See  [Android Developers|ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)

Comment: You may also want to look here: [Android change Horizonal Progress bar color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745814/android-change-horizonal-progress-bar-color)

Answer (score 41):

**Set style for horizontal progress bar**

```
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
```

**Create custom progress drawable: green_progress_drawable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#779d9e9d"
            android:centerColor="#995a5d5a"
            android:centerY="0.75"
            android:endColor="#ff747674"
            android:angle="270"
            />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    >
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#33FF33"
                android:endColor="#008000"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

**My progressbar code:**

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/green_progress_drawable"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"

        android:id="@+id/mf_progress_bar"
        app:layout_widthPercent="80%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="8%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
```

Code credit to @Ryan https://stackoverflow.com/a/5745923/3879847

**My output:**

[image]
I hope this post maybe helpful for someone..

Comment: You forgot to close layer-list tag in green_progress_drawable.xml