# How to Change Horizontal ProgressBar start color and end Color gradient

Tags: android, xml

I have design a horizontal progressBar using xml,But I want color of progressBar color gradient change when progressBar Increase. As per given view in Image.

[image: start color and end color with horizontal gradient]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android

Comment: Create a drawable, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change progress bar's progress color in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android)

Comment: Hi guys thanks for response ,But i am not talking about color Change I would like to change progressColor change like gradient view, means start color and end color different, @junaid hafeez,@asfk,@ajay.

Comment: @RamchandraSingh see, i have posted an answer for you. lemme know if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you need to create custom horizontal progress bar for that

this question also asked her

[How to create Custom Horizontal progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306710/how-to-create-custom-horizontal-progress-bar)

here is official blog

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Comment: I won't this. this is not helpful.

Comment: @RamchandraSingh you have to code ,if you want to achieve something, not every thing you get ready.

Answer (score 0):

make a drawable file an putt this code in it

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#ffb833"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid
                    android:color=" #f3d59d "
                    android:angle="270"
                    />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and in your xml of progressbar add this line

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/your_drawable_file_name"
```