# How to change default ProgressBar circle color on Android

Tags: android, styles, overriding, geometry, android-progressbar

I am currently using an external library in my Android project imported via gradle.
This library show a notification bar with a ProgressBar circle.
This is the code I found in it's sources :

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            style="@style/SuperActivityToast_Progress_ProgressBar"/>
```

The style associated is this one :

```
<style name="SuperActivityToast_Progress_ProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:layout_width">32dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">8dp</item>
</style>
```

If I understand correclty, the color of the circle shown is derived from the default one ( green on my phone ).
I need to change it!

Now, I can't modify the source code, and the library itself doesn't offer me the possibility to set the style programmatically.

There is a way to change the **default** style at app level or better override this specific style?

Thanks
Davide

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android change Horizonal Progress bar color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745814/android-change-horizonal-progress-bar-color)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After several attempts I found a solution :

```
ProgressBar progBar = (ProgressBar) context.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
if (progBar != null) {
    progBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    progBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    progBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
}
```

Simply, i'll get a reference of the progress bar object created by the library and i change it's attributes. ( in my activity i must do that in a "OnStart" method otherwise it is null )
The most important part is the "setColorFilter" that do the magic.

Comment: Mode.MULTIPLY will multiply the color with progressbar color, if someone wants pure solid color then use PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP

Answer (score 62):

If you are using the **AppCompat theme**, it uses the **accentColor** to tint the circle.

If you want to tint it to a different color than the Theme, then you should consider using **ThemeOverylay**. E.g. If you want to make the circle tint `red` you could do the following:

in your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="RedAccent" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorAccent">#F00</item>
</style>
```

in your `ProgressBar`, set the theme to be `RedAccent`.

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:theme="@style/RedAccent"/>
```

And your circle will now be in red color!

Comment: thanks! quick and easy solution that works however only after referencing the theme by including "@style" so android:theme="@style/RedAccent" - thanks

Comment: Yea @CliveSargeant, good catch. it needs to be '@style/' as we are referencing style. I have updated the answer.

Comment: That's a really useful approach. I hadn't realised we could override the application styles in this way!

Comment: you are the definition of a legend

Comment: this solution didn't work for me, I had to set `colorControlActivated` as described in one of the answers below

Comment: Great answer compared to ALL the other solutions.

Answer (score 12):

For future references, this change has worked for me is:

Changing the `colorControlActivated` within `AppTheme` in your **values/styles.xml** file:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    ....
    <!-- Color for circle in progress bar -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#DC0808</item>
</style>
```

With this approach, you do not need to perform any action on your `<ProgressBar/>` tag within your xml file.

Comment: Would colorControlActivated affect other things? If so, which ? And is it behaving differently for dark theme?

Comment: @VivekPratapSingh Do you have the AppTheme set in your manifest file?  
`<application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

Answer (score 8):

Just add color in **ProgressBar** like below :

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimary"  // add color here
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

Comment: Note that `indeterminateTint` is only available from API Level 21 and higer!

Comment: stayed mass like the pest